# New String value on each execution

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

There are 5 string values  (List).  Every time the code is executed it should pick up a different value from the previous one.

Comment: ehm ... ok? and what is stopping you from writing the code to do so?

Comment: generate a random number according to list size and get that index value and print

Answer (score 2):

The way you ask the question doesn't really fit to stackoverflow, as you are asking for a rather basic technique and do not provide at all what you have tried so far. I'll answer you nonetheless.

You'd need to save the last picked String (or its index, a hash, some representation of your choice, ...) to a file, then when executing the code again you'd pick a random int, check if the File exists and if yes pick a new random Int until !list[random].equals(lastString). Again, save that string to said file.

Plus, you need to specify what exactly you mean by code being executed again. Are we speaking about persistent or temporal memory?

Answer (score 0):

Thats the way to get a value from the same "pool" of numbers if your question was like that you could use the code from below.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  private static ArrayList<String> YourList = new ArrayList<String>(); // creates your List

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      YourList.add(Integer.toString(i)); // fills it with random values
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      String return_value = GetValue(); // returns the string you wanna output
      System.out.println(return_value); // output
    }
  }

  private static String GetValue() {
    Random r = new Random(); // new random created
    int index = r.nextInt(5); // get a new random index to select from your list
    String temp = YourList.get(index); // cast the valu from the list to a temp String
    return temp; // reutrn statement
  }
}
```

If you dont want to use the same number again you will need to add the line

```
YourList.remove(index)
```

into the function GetValue().

And change

```
int index = r.nextInt(5);
```

into

```
int index = r.nextInt(YourList.length);
```

I hope this helps